# Vue how push object with specific key to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on an `vue`-application where I have a component for driving licenses.

I have the following:

```
data() {
   return {
     custom_licenses: [],
     basic_licenses: []
   }
}
```

within my methods, I have this:

```
regular_licenses() {
  this.$store.dispatch("license/read").then(response => {
    response.licenses.map((license, key) => {
      // PUSH LICENSES WITH TYPE 'BASIC' TO this.basic_licenses
      // PUSH LICENSES WITH TYPE 'CUSTOM' TO this.custom_licenses
    });
  });
},
```

and in my created() i have this:

```
created() {
   this.regular_licenses()
}
```

The response from my dispatch, returns this:

```
licenses: 
 [
   {
     id: 1, 
     type: 'basic', 
     name: 'AMa'
   },
   {
     id: 2, 
     type: 'basic', 
     name: 'A2'
   }, 
   {
     id: 3, 
     type: 'basic', 
     name: 'C'
   },
   {
     id: 4, 
     type: 'custom', 
     name: 'C1'
   }, 
   {
     id: 5, 
     type: 'custom', 
     name: 'D'
   },

   and so on...
 ]
```

Now I want to loop through the array and separate or push them into `custom_licenses` and `basic_licenses` based on the `type`-attribute - how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
regular_licenses() {
  this.$store.dispatch("license/read").then(response => {
    response.licenses.map((license, key) => {
      switch (license.type)
        case 'basic':
          this.basic_licenses.push({ ...license });
          break;
        case 'custom':
          this.custom_licenses.push({ ...license });
          break;
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Code Block:

```
 response.licenses.map((license, key) => {
   // PUSH LICENSES WITH TYPE 'BASIC' TO this.basic_licenses
    if(license['type'] == 'basic') {
        //deep clone
        let tmpLicense = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(license));
        basic_licenses.push(tmpLicense);
    } else if(license['type'] == 'custom') {
    // PUSH LICENSES WITH TYPE 'CUSTOM' TO this.custom_licenses        
        //deep clone
        let tmpLicense = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(license));
        custom_licenses.push(tmpLicense);
    }  
  });
```